# What was the first laptop to support two external monitors?

Tags: laptop

Looking at https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Dock and https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-7500.c645 I suspect docked ThinkPads around 2000-2001 were able to run two external monitors perhaps even with the panel on. I am unable to confirm this.

So the first question: was the T20 and contemporaries capable of doing this? The ThinkPad T43 from 2005 is confirmed by this [thread](https://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?p=431827) to run dual monitors but what about the older ones?

What was the first laptop, probably a docking station which shipped with two dedicated display outputs? This question always aimed to discover the evolution of mobile graphics chipsets used in portable devices thus the answers to an earlier version of this are skirting it thus the rewrite. It is utterly uninteresting in here that portable computers used to support expansion cards or that text terminals could be attached to them -- like to every computer even well before any portable computers were made.

Comment: I can confirm from personal experience my T43 would do 2 external monitors.  That was my usual setup.

Answer (score 20):

> What was the first laptop to support two external monitors?

Wouldn't that be any laptop (or schleppable) that offers an ISA (or PC-Card) slot? After all, already the very first IBM-PC was capable to support multiple graphics cards with multiple screens(*1). The fact that later machines may combine those into a single board or chip does not really change it, or would it?

Likewise is dual screen support for practical application strictly not really a hardware issue, but a software or better OS problem.

So let's start the list with the

- **1985 [Sharp PC-7000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_PC-7000)**, whose internal display could be redirected to an external screen, while the expansion unit provided another ISA-Slot (beside huge 10 MB HDD).
- While the **[1986 IBM Convertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_Convertible)** did alow removal of the build in LCD and usage of an external screen, addition of other cards were possible,but not supported by IBM products.
- **1987 [Toshiba T3100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_T3100)**.It's docking station (expansion unit) offered 5 ISA slots -enough for one of those 'hacker' setup we know from movies :))
- The same year (1987) Toshiba integrated two slots into the base [T3200](https://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/4435/Toshiba-T3200/) system. [Good bye docking station :))](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28002/what-was-the-first-laptop-to-support-two-external-monitors#comment100490_28005)

Beside those laptop computers like we imagine it today there was a whole world of lunchbox computing. The 1985 [Morrow Pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrow_Pivot_II) and 1986 Zenith Z171 eventually being the creator of that form factor. While these two didn't have build in slots, later units did. In fact, a unit style [still build today](https://www.theportablepc.com/), because of slots.

During the 1990 next to all available laptop could be fitted with additional screens thanks to [PCMCIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Computer_Memory_Card_International_Association)/[PC-Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Card) slots becoming standard. A move that got repeated with USB-Cards.

Bottom line: **Hardware was always fit for dual/multiple screens,it's been a software issue to bring it into every day usage.**

---

*1 - For developers (including me) it was quite common to have CGA and MDA (or Hercules in my case) in one's machine. Not so much for developing for different customers, but having a second screen for debugging without damaging the user side output on the other.

Comment: Interesting.  I never ever saw a PCMCIA/PC card used for an external monitor.  I think all I ever saw them for was networking (including I think ISDN).

Comment: @davidbak from basic VGA all the way to (somewha) modern [GPU type cards](http://www.hisdigital.com/gb/product2-396.shtml)

Comment: Toshiba's T3200 (released the year after the T3100?) has two ISA slots built-in, rather than needing an expansion unit.

Comment: @Kaz Great point, added, thanks.

Comment: I nearly voted to close the question for being off-topic (way to recent; the IBM T43 is not retro, I'd barely even consider it dated). But your answer brings the question back into on-topic.

Comment: @Kaz I had a T3200; those ISA slots were a right pain to get into - and a bit tight on space given how big early ISA soundcards could be

Comment: @OmarandLorraine https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/965/3722 three years ago already Windows 2000 was considered retro. That's contemporary with the T20 which I started with as a possibility. The T43 was merely an example, an upper age limit. 

I will repost this with "two video specific outputs built in". These answers here are sophistry.

Answer (score 10):

This depends on what you mean be an external monitor and what for you intend them to use.

Notice the following:

- There are USB-based monitors, and [USB 1.1 to VGA adaptors](https://www.acs-services.de/product_info.php?language=en&info=p771048_logilink-usb-1-1-to-vga-display-adapter--black--0-3m---usb1-1-a-male-to-hddb15-female.html) so any computer with an USB port would satisfy.
- If a computer has network capabilities, the screen raster via terminal services (on Windows) or X-Window system (on Linux) can be sent via network to any external device, a computer or thin client. The network connection can be established via serial or parralel port as well or via modem.
- If you accept text-based external console, then it can be connected via a serial or parallel port. So, any computer having more than one serial or parallel port can be connected to several  monitors. There are also ways to attach several devices to one port.
- If a device has system bus slot exposed, virtually any device or multiple devices can be connected to it.

So, basically, your question boils down to what is counted as a first laptop, because nearly any computer has means of attaching more than one monitor to it.

For instance, the first computer considered to be laptop, [Osborne 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osborne_1) had one serial and one parallel port and run CP/M operating system which supported several terminal devices (although only one user, so one could use only one terminal at a time by using the command `STAT CON:=TTY:` for serial port or `STAT CON:=PRN:` for parallel port). So, one could easily attach two display terminals to it besides the embedded screen.

Comment: Interesting approach. I would have bet on some sort of portable Unix workstation to be the first, but your argument makes sense.

Comment: I should have specified "shipped with two display specific outputs".

Comment: @chx serial ports were initially intended for teletype terminals, which you can see from their name "TTY" in CP/M, "tty" in Unix, "TT" in RT-11. By the mid-1970s the teletype terminals were mostly replaced with display terminals.